# Skewed and Distorted Texture Application

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, edges, texture-coordinates

I'm struggling here crew!
Why can't I get this fairly simple idea to work...

I need to create a mesh to fit over a model of a sealed cosmetics tube, and effectively emulate a printable area on a real world sealed cosmetics tube.

My process at the moment is;

1. Import the mesh in from a separate CAD program (assume it is not created by me)
2. Create a cylinder primitive around it
3. Z align the cylinder, and use the upper and lower bounds of the real world print area to crop the top and bottom of the cylinder to represent this size.
4. edit mode -> face select - > delete top and bottom face of cylinder
5. Subdivide the cylinder a few times to help the next step...
6. Apply modifier - shrinkwrap to the tube (wrap method = project, snap mode = on surface, negative = checked, and offset created appropriately to prevent z-fighting)
7. Inspecting the UV and it all looks good - nice quads as expected from the cylinder primitive.
8. However, the mesh itself is now distorted from conforming to the face of the tube during the shrinkwrap process. You can see in the image that partway up the mesh, the edges begin to taper in toward the centre. This distorts any artwork which is applied to the tube, giving it a tapering effect like the star-wars opening scroll. This is undesirable.

Is there a way that I can correct the shrinkwrapped mesh so that it does not distort the artwork texture when it is applied?

Here are some images;

[image]
[image]

Comment: The topology seems bad, why don't you do it clean? As for the texture, maybe simply use Unwrap >Project from View?

Comment: ... agreed  .. in real life, if the printed skin was going to stretch on application, then the artwork would have to be pre-stretched the other way, Are seams acceptable down the sides of the tube?

Comment: Hi @moonboots when you say "do it clean" can you elaborate on this? 
As for UV projection method...Project from view doesn't work for me as it mashes the front and back of the UV map ontop of each other...(ie if i'm projecting from -y, then it overlays -y and +y on the same region in the UV), when I need the UV to work like wrapped around band of printable area. Possible I am getting this wrong as well though tbh :P

Comment: @RobinBetts in real life tubes are printed when they are still a flat sheet of material, ie before any deformation of the material occurs.
Printing proofs for artworks on tubes are typically a rectangular region which is the height of the printable space, and the circumference of the tube (with a little tolerance), and I want to be able to export a UV that adheres to this industry standard.

I have a seam down the left side of the print region mesh (where the mesh intersects -x) and this is how it will be for all the meshes, as this is consistent with real world manufacturing

Comment: You can only select the front faces and U >Project from View, then select the rest of the mesh, unwrap and put over a yellow part of your image

Comment: @moonboots hey nice one, thanks for the idea.
Is there a command to select faces only on the front (-y)? Or are you suggesting manual selection? I'm trying to automate this process with python, so ideally I can command it rather than rely on mouse over....
definitely appreciative of your help my friend :)

Comment: Just select with the B (box) selection, don't enable X-ray so that you don't select the back

Comment: @moonboots sweet as, but is there a command for this rather than B+draw a marquee over the object?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how you could automate that :/

Comment: @moonboots that's ok - this is a good start point for a possible route to success. Thanks for taking some time to share your expertise, I appreciate you :)